# Web pages - tree hierarchy

Tags: treeview, html

How can I see all files and subdirectiories at http://www.anywebpage.com/directory. When I visit some page like http://www.anywebpage.com/directory, it shows me only index.html but I would like to see tree hierarchy - files and subdirectories. Is it possible?

Comment: do you mean on your own site or on _any_ site?

Comment: Confusing question. When you enter a web page, you go to the index file automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean:

> Can I request a directory listing from arbitrary third party web servers?

Then the answer is a resounding **no**

If you mean:

> Can I configure my web-server to serve up a directory listing but also have a default index page that is not that listing?

Then it is possible, but I'm not aware of any web server that has such a feature built in, so you will need to write a (or find a third party) script that will give you those listings when you hit a different URL (that you choose).

Comment: I do not think my web-server. So there is no way how to see another files except index?

Comment: Correct, when I said "**no**", I really did mean "no".

Answer (score 1):

When you enter a directory, you go to the index file automatically. 
If there is no index file, You will most likely see all the files in the directory.